# How can automatically update a directory/repo which is a subset of another directory/repo?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-submodules, githooks

I have the following problem I'm unable to resolve :

I have two version controlled directories on my local machine. One is `dirA` which holds a lot of my stuff and is a private repo I don't want to share. The other is `dirB`, a small public repo with files I do want to share, it's mainly for others to clone and pull, the changes all come from me.

The thing is that `dirB` holds files which are all coming from `dirA`, it's basically a subset of `dirA` though it has another structure.

Anytime I make changes to the files in `dirA` that are **also** in `dirB`, I'd like to update `dirB` and then push the updated files to the public repo.

I tried using `rsync` and `unison` but I have to do it by hand anytime I update the specific files I mentioned, it's not very efficient. I gathered git submodules or hooks could help me but I don't understand what tool I should use.

In substance, I have :

```
dirA/ (larger private repo with my stuff)
|
|--- file1
|
|--- file2
.
.
.--- fileN
```

and

```
dirB/ (public repo that I want to update only when the relevant files from dirA are updated)
|
|--- SubjectA/
|       |
|       |--- file3
|
|--- SubjectB/
        |
        |--- file11
.
.
```

Ideally, I'd like that when I update `dirA` locally and push to remote, `dirB` is updated locally as well and then it'd be pushed to remote as well.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about creating symlinks in dir B of files in your dir A. Whenever A's files are updated they should automatically update their B counterpart

Comment: Symbolic links didn't work for me, it just points to where the files are in `dirA`. So when I push `dirB` to gitlab, I only get a bunch links instead of the actual files.

Comment: Did you try just creating a hardlinks instead. I believe they should sync too and actual files get pushed to your repo, instead of just plain links.

Comment: Originally I thought it didn't work because I believed it didn't point to the same inode. I just tried and it seems to work though!

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Well I did some checks and it seems that once my PDF is compiled from LaTex and does exist, then using hardlinks does work! This fixes most of my problems, thanks!

Comment: posted as answer, in the spirit of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirement is to keep files in sync and also be able to push real files(not plain links) you could simply create hardlinks for files of interest.

You could create a hard link as follows :

```
ln <src-file-path> <path-to-the-link>
```

This should create a hardlink for your file, any changes in original file reflects in the newly created file and pushing to the repository results in a genuine file, not a link.

**NOTE:** Make sure that you don't provide the `-s` switch as it will create a soft-link instead.